# datetime strftime %s crash on windows

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have this piece of code that fails on windows, but works on linux:

```
import datetime as dt

ts = dt.datetime.now().__format__('%s')
#ts == '1479831118'
```

I look into the documentation (Python 3.5) and 'format %s' don't even exist there.

How can I fix this and get the same output from Linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided outputs current time in seconds.

I may recommend to use `time` module.

This will return the same.

```
import time
ts = str(int(time.time()))
```